# Papervision rendering PNGs with transparency thats inside a movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, png, transparent, papervision3d

I'm an actionscript dude - I'm working on a papervision game.

I have an asset of which is 127 pngs in a sequence for an animation.

I can happily project this onto my papervision plane. Problem is, there is no transparency. I Can't use a BitmapFileMaterial as I have many pngs -

can anyone suggest how to do this.

Very very grateful -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading over google - There seems to be a bug -

```
private var movieMat:MovieMaterial = new MovieMaterial(textureMC, true, true)
```

set to

```
private var movieMat:MovieMaterial = new MovieMaterial(textureMC, false, true)
```

and later setting

```
movieMat.movieTransparent = true;
```

seems to work.

---

Uber thanks for your help  -pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

myMaterial.transparent = true

Or something like that, check out the docs if that doesn't work.

Comment: doesn't exist for movie materials

Comment: I did try that, I may be implementing it wrong but it doesn't work - I saw on papervision 3d other people have had trouble with that too.

Comment: Can you post your code? Try setting it through the constructor function as well, rather than after.

Answer (score 0):

this is my code so far. A simplified version *edit* - Papervision 2.0.0

```
package com.strangemother.gameObjects
{

    import org.papervision3d.materials.MovieMaterial;
    import org.papervision3d.objects.DisplayObject3D;
    import org.papervision3d.objects.primitives.Plane;

    public class Biorod extends DisplayObject3D
    {
        /*
        My flash movieclip with 127 pngs in sequence
        */
        private var textureMC:BiorodTexture     = new BiorodTexture();
        private var movieMat:MovieMaterial      = new MovieMaterial(textureMC, true, true)

        var plane:Plane = new Plane(movieMat, 300,300,1,1);


        public function Biorod()
        {
            textureMC.id                = 'biorod';
            movieMat.animated       = true;
            movieMat.doubleSided        = true;
        //  movieMat.interactive        = true;
            movieMat.smooth             = true;
            movieMat.movieTransparent   = true; 

            this.addChild(plane);
        }


    }
}
```